# Why doesn't this renew work when it has a jQuery argument

Tags: jquery, html, text, countdown

I have the following in my javascript header:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#renew").click(function() {
        // Here we want to do an asynchronous ajax update of the time on the queue entry
        alert('reset to '+$('#time-div').text());
        $("#remainingTime").countdown('option',{until: $('#time-div').text(), format: "mS", expiryText: "Entry Released"});
    });
    $("#remainingTime").countdown({until: $('#time-div').text(), format: "mS", expiryText: "Entry Released"});
});
```

I have a div with the id of 'time-div' where it has

```
<div id='time-div'>+120s</div>
```

I'm using the 
to do the countdown.

If I put until: '+30s' where I have until: $('#time-div').text(),
      then my div 'remaining-time' shows a count down as it should.

When I have the $('#time-div').text(), it always shows zero!  Now the alert you see in the click function, displays the alert with '+120s' properly, showing that the div does have that value.

What is wrong here?  How does one use a value from a div in the until: argument?

Comment: Does your alert give you what you expect?

Comment: Yes it does.  It displays '+120s'

Comment: Also, using the string '+120s' produces the countdown.  However, the previous '#renew' click function, which catches the click ( alert box again ), does not restart the countdown, which I think it should.

Answer (score 0):

it's probably better to use a `data` attribute here, although I can't be sure why the text isn't working.

try this:

```
<div id='time-div' data-time_div="+120s">+120s</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#renew").click(function() {
        var time = $('#time-div').data('time_div');
        // Here we want to do an asynchronous ajax update of the time on the queue entry
        alert('reset to '+ time);
        $("#remainingTime").countdown('option',{until: time, format: "mS", expiryText: "Entry Released"});
    });
    $("#remainingTime").countdown({until: $('#time-div').data('time_div'), format: "mS", expiryText: "Entry Released"});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a good try, but no cigar!  I tried var time = $('#time-div').data('time_div'); and var time = $('#time-div').data('#time_div'); and neither worked.  I also tried var time = '+120s'; and that worked fine as the argument to the until:  I don't see why, when I can put the time as you retrieved it into the alert box and it shows correctly and identically to the direct setting, viz. time = '+120s', that it doesn't work.  Bug?  Different "type", what?